# npm local paths - is it possible to import from a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Given the following folder structure that is leveraging [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths):

```
dist
  components
    Button.js
  index.js
src
  components
    Button.js
  index.js
website
  pages
    components
      button.js
  package.json
  ...
package.json
```

**src/components/Button.js**

```
export const VARIANTS = ["primary", "secondary"];

function Button({ variant = "primary"}) {
  ...
}

Button.propTypes = {
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(VARIANTS),
};

export default Button;
```

**src/index.js**

```
export { default as Button } from "./components/Button";
```

**website/package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "design-system": "file:..",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "design-system",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "transpile": "rimraf dist && babel src -d dist",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Importing a `Button` works fine:

**website/pages/components/button.js**

```
import { Button } from "design-system";
```

But, importing directly from a subfolder doesn't work:

**website/pages/components/button.js**

```
import { VARIANTS } from "design-system/components/Button";
```

> This dependency was not found: design-system/components/Button

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried as like 'import { Button, tokens  } from "design-system";' ?

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import from `design-system` like this :

```
import { Button } from "design-system";
```

Because you have a `"main": "dist/index.js"` field in your `package.json` , it's the same as :

```
import { Button } from "design-system/dist/index.js";
```

Which works because the file exist.

To import any other module from your `dist` folder, you have to be specific and start with `design-system/dist`:

```
import { VARIANTS } from "design-system/dist/components/Button";
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work correctly as you expect - my guess is that maybe you've not reinstalled module after updating your code? 
You need to update your `node_module` copy every time you modify your module code since your local module is copied into the `node_modules` folder. Try something like this in your project root:

```
rm -rf node_modules/design-system && npm install
```

and then check if its working.